# Multiple MouseGetPos coordinates

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to figure out how to have an AutoHotKey script save different coordinates through MouseGetPos on different hotkeys at the same time, without one overwriting the other.

I want to make a loop performing some sequence of events. Say at one point I want it to execute the first coordinate that I saved before or during the loop (but before the action), and then I want the script to execute the other coordinate at a later point in the loop.

I want the coordinates to be able to be preset (instead of pressing Hotkey1 before the action of hotkey1 and consequently hotkey2 after hotkey1 to ensure one is not overwritten).

**An example of this would be:**

*If one hotkey saves one coordinate:*

```
hotkey1::
MouseGetPos, posx, posy,

// If inserted into a loop, it would be:
MouseMove, %posx%, %posy%,
```

*One hotkey saves another coordinate:*

```
hotkey2::
MouseGetPos, posx1, posy1,

// In loop:
MouseMove, %posx1%, %posy1%,
```

*If inputted into a random loop*

```
#SingleInstance Force
SendMode Input
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey, 2
#NoEnv
#Persistent
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
SetMouseDelay, -1

Process, Priority, , H
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0

SetKeyDelay, 0, 10, Play 
SetMouseDelay, 10, Play

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

hotkey1::
MouseGetPos, posx, posy,
return

hotkey2::
MouseGetPos, posx1, posy1,
return

Toggle=0
f::
Toggle := !Toggle
Loop
{
 If Toggle
   {
    Send {a}
    sleep 100
    MouseMove, %posx%, %posy%, // Say I want it to move to bottom left corner
    Send {LButton}
    sleep 100

            If !Toggle
                Break

    MouseMove, %posx1%, %posy1%, // Say this coordinate would be top-right corner
    Send {LButton}
    sleep 100
    Send {c}
   }
}
return

q::ExitApp
```

If I trigger hotkey1 and hotkey2 in that order, hotkey1 would get saved then overwritten by hotkey2, making hotkey1 the same coordinate as hotkey2. I would want 2 separately saved coordinates.

Do I do that by having one script trigger another script or can this be done in a single script?

Comment: "hotkey1" and "hotkey2" do not overwrite each other. You have different output variables for each ("posx" and "posy" vs "posx1" and "posy1"). Have you tried running it? It appears that it will work how you want. On an unrelated note, you have a lot of unnecessary header commands and no way out of your loop.

Comment: You're right, the code above was mostly condensed to narrow it down to the problem. It is edited accordingly. 

I did run it multiple times, but every time I tried, the coordinate saved by hotkey1 and hotkey2 would depend on what was pressed last, as both would somehow correspond to each other. 

I am going to test whether my MouseMove syntax is incorrect and try:
`MouseMove, % pos(insert number depending on hotkey coordinate)x, % pos(insert number depending on hotkey coordinate)y`
I suspect that might be part of the issue with the code, but I'll report back later.

Comment: That still looks like it should work correctly. Would you mind posting your exact "hotkey1" and "hotkey2" portions of code related to `MouseGetPos`?